# Anymap: Setting zIndex for single map points

Tags: anychart

is it possible to set the zIndex of a single marker on the map? I have multiple series implemented on a map and the label of a point is sometimes overlapped by another point. So I was thinking about raising the zIndex of the selected point via the pointsselected event, but I am just able to set the zIndex to the whole series.

Then I tried to raise the zIndex of the current series but that doesn't work well in firefox..

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

1) as of version 7.13.0 - it is not possible to set zIndex to the individual point, AnyChart will try to fix it in the next update.

**update:** This feature is available now, you can set zIndex for each particular point, like http://jsfiddle.net/4sskmb8k/3/

2) we tested Firefox 52 Win and 52 Mac and it seems to be working fine

```
firstSeries = chart.marker(dataSet1);
secondSeries = chart.marker(dataSet2).type('star').size(10);
chart.container('container').draw();
firstSeries.zIndex(secondSeries.zIndex()+1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4sskmb8k/2/ 
Do you use another version or other settings?

Answer (score 0):

Version 7.14.0 of AnyChart fixes this problem http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/history/